# Make user object available to all Controllers in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework, session, bootstrapping, zend-auth

I'm using Zend_Auth to identify a user in my application.
This creates a session with the userobject.

My question is how do I make this object available to every Controller and action, so I don't have to pull it out of the session every time I need data from this object?

I'm guessing this should be done in bootstrap.php or index.php but I don't really know how to makte it available to every controller.. so any code examples would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bootstrap` and `index.php` are probably too early. Since routing is not yet done, there is no controller into which to inject your `$user` object.

Several possibilities come to mind:

**Use a BaseController**

Create a `BaseController` form which all your other controllers extend. In the `init()` method of your base controller, you can place your assignment

```
$this->_user = Zend_Auth::hasIdentity() ? Zend_Auth::getIdentity() : null;
```

Then `$this->_user` will be available everywhere your controller actions.

But many people deride the idea of a BaseController. Better to use an Action Helper, described below.

**Use an Action Helper**

Create an [action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) whose `direct()` method returns the `$user` object created in the same way as above. Then in your controllers, you can access it as `$this->_helper->user`.

Precisely what you name the helper class and where you place it are are dependent upon paths and namespaces you set in the `Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker` using the `addPath()` method.

**Use a Controller Plugin**

Listed for completeness. But really, the best thing IMO is an Action Helper above.

Comment: Thorough answer. I too would recommend the action helper based approach, as it is the most flexible.